# Kivy: How to Show Loading Screen For My Function

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am a beginner on Kivy so i hope you can help me about this issue

1. I have underover and side functions that show us some results.
   Interface works perfect but when i click a button I wait for the process to be completed that takes 2-3 seconds according to device. I want to show a loading screen during this process for my twu functions (underover, side)

2)One more thing how i can disable screenmanager.transition for this code as well?

Thanks very much for all comments

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.metrics import dp
import requests
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior

        
class WrappedLabel(Label):
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(WrappedLabel, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.bind(
            width=lambda *x: self.setter('text_size')(self, (self.width, None)),
            texture_size = lambda *x: self.setter('height')(self, self.texture_size[1]))

class Tor(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Tor, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.status = True
        self.data = self.datas()
        self.Today = self.todayMatches()


    def homepage(self, s_image, screenmanager):
        
        if(screenmanager.current == 'underover_screen' or screenmanager.current == 'side_screen' or screenmanager.current == 'privacy_policy_screen'):
            screenmanager.transition.direction = 'right'
        screenmanager.current = 'homepage_screen'  

    def underOver(self, s_image, screenmanager):

        if(screenmanager.current == 'homepage_screen' or screenmanager.current == 'side_screen' or screenmanager.current == 'privacy_policy_screen'):
            screenmanager.transition.direction = 'left'
        screenmanager.current = 'underover_screen'



        print("""    
        Welcome to Under Over Goal Statics
        """)
        
        for i in range(len(self.Today[0])):

            # Some Calculations here #
            
            box = BoxLayout(size_hint_y = None, height = dp(50))
            sira = WrappedLabel(text = f'{i+1}', font_name = 'fonts/Lcd.ttf', font_size = dp(15), size_hint = (0.10, 1), halign='center' )
            evsahibi = WrappedLabel(text = f'{self.Today[0][i]}', font_name = 'Roboto', font_size = dp(15), size_hint = (0.225, 1), halign='center' )
            deplasman = WrappedLabel(text = f'{self.Today[1][i]}', font_name = 'Roboto', font_size = dp(15), size_hint = (0.225, 1), halign='center' )
            macbasigol = WrappedLabel(text = f'{sonuc}', font_name = 'fonts/Lcd.ttf', font_size = dp(15), size_hint = (0.15, 1), halign='center' )
            ust_2_5 = WrappedLabel(text = f'{predict2_5result}', font_name = 'fonts/Lcd.ttf', font_size = dp(15), size_hint = (0.15, 1), halign='center' )
            ust_3_5 = WrappedLabel(text = f'{predict3_5result}', font_name = 'fonts/Lcd.ttf', font_size = dp(15), size_hint = (0.15, 1), halign='center' )
            box.add_widget(sira)
            box.add_widget(evsahibi)
            box.add_widget(deplasman)
            box.add_widget(macbasigol)
            box.add_widget(ust_2_5)
            box.add_widget(ust_3_5)
            self.ids.gridsonuc.add_widget(box)

    def side(self, s_image, screenmanager):

        if(screenmanager.current == 'homepage_screen' or screenmanager.current == 'underover_screen' or screenmanager.current == 'privacy_policy_screen'):
            screenmanager.transition.direction = 'left'
        screenmanager.current = 'side_screen'

        print("""    
        Welcome to Winnig Side Statics
        """)

        for i in range(len(self.Today[0])):

            # Some Calculations here #

            box2 = BoxLayout(size_hint_y = None, height = 50)
            sira2 = WrappedLabel(text = f'{i+1}', font_name = 'fonts/Lcd.ttf', font_size = dp(15), size_hint = (0.10, 1), halign='center' )
            evsahibi2 = WrappedLabel(text = f'{self.Today[0][i]}', font_name = 'Roboto', font_size = dp(15), size_hint = (0.225, 1), halign='center' )
            deplasman2 = WrappedLabel(text = f'{self.Today[1][i]}', font_name = 'Roboto', font_size = dp(15), size_hint = (0.225, 1), halign='center' )
            evkazanmasans = WrappedLabel(text = f'{homeWin}', font_name = 'fonts/Lcd.ttf', font_size = dp(15), size_hint = (0.15, 1), halign='center' )
            beraberliksans = WrappedLabel(text = f'{draw}', font_name = 'fonts/Lcd.ttf', font_size = dp(15), size_hint = (0.15, 1), halign='center' )
            deplasmansans = WrappedLabel(text = f'{awayWin}', font_name = 'fonts/Lcd.ttf', font_size = dp(15), size_hint = (0.15, 1), halign='center' )
            box2.add_widget(sira2)
            box2.add_widget(evsahibi2)
            box2.add_widget(deplasman2)
            box2.add_widget(evkazanmasans)
            box2.add_widget(beraberliksans)
            box2.add_widget(deplasmansans)
            self.ids.gridsonuc2.add_widget(box2)



class BetApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Tor()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    BetApp().run()
```

KV file:

```
Tor:
<Tor>:
    ScreenManager:
        id: sm
        size: root.width, root.height
        Screen:
            name: 'homepage_screen'
            Image:
                source: 'images/homepage_background.png'
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: False
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: 1, 0.10
                Button:
                    id: underOver_button_homege
                    on_press: root.underOver(img_underOver, sm)
                    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0                 
                    Image:
                        id: img_underOver
                        source: 'images/underover_button.png'
                        allow_stretch: True
                        keep_ratio: False
                        size: self.parent.size
                        pos: underOver_button_homege.pos
                Button:
                    id: side_button_homepage
                    on_press: root.side(img_side, sm)
                    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0                
                    Image:
                        id: img_side
                        source: 'images/side_button.png' 
                        allow_stretch: True
                        keep_ratio: False
                        size: self.parent.size
                        pos: side_button_homepage.pos                   
        Screen:
            name: 'underover_screen'
            Image: 
                source: 'images/underover_background.png'
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: False
            BoxLayout:
                spacing: '20dp'
                orientation: 'vertical'    
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint: 1, 0.10
                    Label:
                        size_hint: 0.10, 1
                        text: '#'
                        font_name: 'fonts/Lcd.ttf'
                        font_size: '30dp'
                        color: 1, 0.4, 0.769, 1
                    Label:
                        size_hint: 0.225, 1
                        text: 'T1'
                        font_name: 'fonts/Lcd.ttf'
                        font_size: '30dp'
                        color: 1, 0.4, 0.769, 1
                    Label:
                        size_hint: 0.225, 1
                        text: 'T2'
                        font_name: 'fonts/Lcd.ttf'
                        font_size: '30dp'
                        color: 1, 0.4, 0.769, 1
                    Label:
                        size_hint: 0.15, 1
                        text: 'G.A'
                        font_name: 'fonts/Lcd.ttf'
                        font_size: '30dp'
                        color: 1, 0.4, 0.769, 1
                    Label:
                        size_hint: 0.15, 1
                        text: '2.5'
                        font_name: 'fonts/Lcd.ttf'
                        font_size: '30dp'
                        color: 1, 0.4, 0.769, 1
                    Label:
                        size_hint: 0.15, 1
                        text: '3.5'
                        font_name: 'fonts/Lcd.ttf'
                        font_size: '30dp'
                        color: 1, 0.4, 0.769, 1
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint: 1, 0.80  
                    ScrollView:
                        bar_margin: '5dp'
                        bar_color: 1, 0.4, 0.769, 1 
                        bar_width: '5dp'
                        bar_inactive_color: 1, 0.4, 0.769, 1
                        GridLayout:                            
                            id: gridsonuc
                            cols: 1
                            spacing: '50dp'
                            size_hint_y: None
                            height: self.minimum_height        
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint: 1, 0.10
                    Button:
                        id: home_button_underOver
                        on_press: root.homepage(img_home, sm)
                        background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0                 
                        Image:
                            id: img_home
                            source: 'images/home_button.png'
                            allow_stretch: True
                            keep_ratio: False
                            size: self.parent.size
                            pos: home_button_underOver.pos
                    Button:
                        id: side_button_underOver
                        on_press: root.side(img_side, sm)
                        background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0                
                        Image:
                            id: img_side
                            source: 'images/side_button.png' 
                            allow_stretch: True
                            keep_ratio: False
                            size: self.parent.size
                            pos: side_button_underOver.pos         
        Screen:
            name: 'side_screen'
            Image:
                source: 'images/side_background.png'
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: False
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                spacing: '20dp'    
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint: 1, 0.10
                    Label:
                        size_hint: 0.10, 1
                        text: '#'
                        font_name: 'fonts/Lcd.ttf'
                        font_size: '30dp'
                        color: 1, 0.4, 0.769, 1
                    Label:
                        size_hint: 0.225, 1
                        text: 'T1'                        
                        font_name: 'fonts/Lcd.ttf'
                        font_size: '30dp'
                        color: 1, 0.4, 0.769, 1
                    Label:
                        size_hint: 0.225, 1
                        text: 'T2'
                        font_name: 'fonts/Lcd.ttf'
                        font_size: '30dp'
                        color: 1, 0.4, 0.769, 1
                    Label:
                        size_hint: 0.15, 1
                        text: 'H'
                        font_name: 'fonts/Lcd.ttf'
                        font_size: '30dp'
                        color: 1, 0.4, 0.769, 1
                    Label:
                        size_hint: 0.15, 1
                        text: 'D'
                        font_name: 'fonts/Lcd.ttf'
                        font_size: '30dp'
                        color: 1, 0.4, 0.769, 1
                    Label:
                        size_hint: 0.15, 1
                        text: 'A'
                        font_name: 'fonts/Lcd.ttf'
                        font_size: '30dp'
                        color: 1, 0.4, 0.769, 1
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint: 1, 0.80  
                    ScrollView:
                        bar_margin: '5dp'
                        bar_color: 1, 0.4, 0.769, 1 
                        bar_width: '5dp'
                        bar_inactive_color: 1, 0.4, 0.769, 1
                        GridLayout:
                            id: gridsonuc2
                            cols: 1
                            spacing: '50dp'
                            size_hint_y: None
                            height: self.minimum_height    
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint: 1, 0.10
                    Button:
                        id: home_button_side
                        on_press: root.homepage(img_home, sm)
                        background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0                 
                        Image:
                            id: img_home
                            source: 'images/home_button.png'
                            allow_stretch: True
                            keep_ratio: False
                            size: self.parent.size
                            pos: home_button_side.pos
                    Button:
                        id: underOver_button_side
                        on_press: root.underOver(img_underOver, sm)
                        background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0                 
                        Image:
                            id: img_underOver
                            source: 'images/underover_button.png'
                            allow_stretch: True
                            keep_ratio: False
                            size: self.parent.size
                            pos: underOver_button_side.pos    
                  
        Screen:
            name: 'privacy_policy_screen'
            Image:
                source: 'images/privacy_policy_background.png'
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: False
```

Comment: I would say it's a bad design... nothing is triggered. I have played with your code and it's not doing anything.

Comment: How about using a `Popup` with something like a `Please Wait` `Label` in it.

Comment: I find a solutin it works but there are another problem this time. First of all solution is popup.  I will share solution. Probem is each time when i click button it adds all results again and again.  I press button there is 1,2,3,4,5 results than i go homepage then back to click button again, it shows 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5 i mean it adds results to same screen is this caching? How can i fix this

Answer (score 0):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.metrics import dp
import requests
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
import threading
from kivy.clock import mainthread
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
import time

# fist add this
class PopupBox(Popup):
    pop_up_text = ObjectProperty()
    def update_pop_up_text(self, p_message):
        self.pop_up_text.text = p_message
        
class WrappedLabel(Label):
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(WrappedLabel, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.bind(
            width=lambda *x: self.setter('text_size')(self, (self.width, None)),
            texture_size = lambda *x: self.setter('height')(self, self.texture_size[1]))

class Tor(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Tor, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.status = True
        self.data = self.datas()
        self.Today = self.todayMatches()


    def homepage(self, s_image, screenmanager):
        
        if(screenmanager.current == 'underover_screen' or screenmanager.current == 'side_screen' or screenmanager.current == 'privacy_policy_screen'):
            screenmanager.transition.direction = 'right'
        screenmanager.current = 'homepage_screen'
  
    # second 1 add this function below
    def show_popup(self):
        self.pop_up = Factory.PopupBox()
        self.pop_up.update_pop_up_text('Loading...')
        self.pop_up.open()      

    def underOver(self, s_image, screenmanager):

        if(screenmanager.current == 'homepage_screen' or screenmanager.current == 'side_screen' or screenmanager.current == 'privacy_policy_screen'):
            screenmanager.transition.direction = 'left'
        screenmanager.current = 'underover_screen'    
          
        # added 3 lines
        self.show_popup()
        mythread = threading.Thread(target=self.underOver_hesaplama)
        mythread.start()
    
    # seperate onderover function and aded 4 lines in it
    @mainthread
    def underOver_hesaplama(self, *args):
        
        # aded 4 lines
        thistime = time.time() 
        while thistime + 2 > time.time(): # 2 seconds
            time.sleep(1)
        self.pop_up.dismiss()

        print("""    
        Welcome to Under Over Goal Statics
        """)
        
        for i in range(len(self.Today[0])):

            # Some Calculations here #
            
            box = BoxLayout(size_hint_y = None, height = dp(50))
            sira = WrappedLabel(text = f'{i+1}', font_name = 'fonts/Lcd.ttf', font_size = dp(15), size_hint = (0.10, 1), halign='center' )
            evsahibi = WrappedLabel(text = f'{self.Today[0][i]}', font_name = 'Roboto', font_size = dp(15), size_hint = (0.225, 1), halign='center' )
            deplasman = WrappedLabel(text = f'{self.Today[1][i]}', font_name = 'Roboto', font_size = dp(15), size_hint = (0.225, 1), halign='center' )
            macbasigol = WrappedLabel(text = f'{sonuc}', font_name = 'fonts/Lcd.ttf', font_size = dp(15), size_hint = (0.15, 1), halign='center' )
            ust_2_5 = WrappedLabel(text = f'{predict2_5result}', font_name = 'fonts/Lcd.ttf', font_size = dp(15), size_hint = (0.15, 1), halign='center' )
            ust_3_5 = WrappedLabel(text = f'{predict3_5result}', font_name = 'fonts/Lcd.ttf', font_size = dp(15), size_hint = (0.15, 1), halign='center' )
            box.add_widget(sira)
            box.add_widget(evsahibi)
            box.add_widget(deplasman)
            box.add_widget(macbasigol)
            box.add_widget(ust_2_5)
            box.add_widget(ust_3_5)
            self.ids.gridsonuc.add_widget(box)

    




class BetApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Tor()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    BetApp().run()
```

KV file

```
<PopupBox>:
    pop_up_text: _pop_up_text
    size_hint: .5, .5
    auto_dismiss: True
    title: 'Data'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            id: _pop_up_text
            text: ''
```

It worked i think but this time there is a problem.
Probem is each time when i click button it adds all results again and again. I press button there is 1,2,3,4,5 results than i go homepage then back to click button again, it shows 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5 i mean it adds results to same screen is this caching? How can i fix this I don't know...